# How do I add a boolean value to each item in a list?

Tags: python, list, boolean, tuples

thanks for taking the time to answer.
I am making a hangman game as a beginner Python Project.\

I have the "word" that I split into a list, with each item being a character of the word.

```
word = "word" 
letters = []
letters[:] = word
print(letters)

["w","o","r","d"]
```

I am not quite sure how to assign a boolean value to each list item, creating tuples, like this:

```
[("w", False),("o", False), ("r", False), ("d", False)]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via `list comprehension`:

```
word = "word"
result = [(char, False) for char in word]
```

via `map` and `lambda`:

```
word = "word"
result = list(map(lambda x: (x, False), char))
```

Comment: Instead of `i`, it might be more readable to use `letter` or `character`

Comment: Replaced `i` with `char` @jakub

Answer (score 1):

I would go for using `zip` and list comprehension

```
word = ["w","o","r","d"]
booleanValues = [False,False,True,True]
lst = [(let,boo) for let,boo in zip(word,booleanValues)]
```

output

```
[('w', False), ('o', False), ('r', True), ('d', True)]
```

Now if you just wanted to assign False to each tuple, you could try the following.

```
word = ["w","o","r","d"]
lst = [(let,False) for let in word]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension

```
word = "word" 
letters = []
letters[:] = word
res = [(val, False) for val in letters]
print(res)
```